# What settings to choose for force directed graph layout in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am visualising a graph of relationships between people with d3. All nodes are connected to a single central node, and then have relationships with other nodes. I've got the basics working, but I'm struggling to work out how to set the parameters like linkDistance, linkStrength, gravity and charge.

Each edge has a rating from 0-5, which I'm then using to compute linkDistance using an inverse linear scale. The main problem is getting the relationships to be represented properly. The central node seems to be much further away than any other node, even though it has the shortest linkDistance with some other nodes. I'm also finding it difficult to find the right settings to get nodes to be an appropriate distance apart.

```
var h = 500, w = 1000

var color = d3.scale.category20()

var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr({ height: h, width: w })

queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "nodes.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "links.json")
    .await(makeDiag);


function makeDiag(error, nodes, links, table) {
    links = links.filter(function(link) {
        if (link.value) return true
    })

    var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,5]).range([20,0])

    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
                    .data(links)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                    .style("stroke-width", 1)

    /* Establish the dynamic force behavor of the nodes */
    var force = d3.layout.force()
                    .nodes(nodes)
                    .links(links)
                    .size([w,h])
                    .linkDistance(function(d) { 
                        if (d.value == 0) return null
                        console.log('in',d.value,'out',scale(d.value))
                        return scale(d.value)
                    })
                    .charge(-1400)
                    .start();
    /* Draw the edges/links between the nodes */
    var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "black")
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "10px")
                    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("r", function(d,i) { return 20 })
                    .attr("opacity", 0.7)
                    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                    .call(force.drag);

    /* Draw the nodes themselves */                

    /* Run the Force effect */
    force.on("tick", function() {
               edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

               nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

               texts.attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + (d.x - 12.5) + "," + (d.y + 5) + ")";
                });


            });
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/6567/)
[full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/6567/embedded/result/)

Comment: I guess that entirely depends on what you mean by "an appropriate distance". Also keep in mind that none of those parameters will allow you to achieve an exact result; they are all just guidelines.

Comment: By appropriate distance I mean in proportion to the 0-5 weighting and other link distances.

Comment: Well, there's really not much you can do apart from trying different values for the various things.